# Show controls in Scrollviewer row along the Scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollview

So I have this scenario in which I am showing a `Grid` inside a `ScrollViewer`.
I want to show a combobox and an image along the scrollbar in a way that it doesn't effect the scrolling functionality,
Something like this:
[image]

Currently whenever the scrollviewer becomes visible it appears in a new row, how can I show it along the controls in the same row?

Here is my xaml design:

```
<DockPanel  LastChildFill="True">

    <!--Top Panel-->
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      --GridContent
    </Grid>

    <!--Bottom Panel-->
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <ComboBox Grid.Column ="0"> 
        </ComboBox>

      <Image Grid.Column="1">

      </Image>
    </Grid>

    <ScrollViewer   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid              
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
          -- Grid Content
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

Currently it appears like this :

[image]

Comment: Unless you want to do some rather involved custom templating, a quick workaround is just hide the horizontalbarvisibility in the scrollviewer, and instead use just a scrollbar bound to the offset and scrollchanged properties of the scrollviewer you want to interact with. Would take longer to make an example than I have in free time though, sorry amigo

Comment: In your example, your ScrollViewer is not in the same grid as the combo box and the image.  Is that intentional??

Comment: @Bryan yes because I don't want these controls to flow with the grid content when user scrolls.

Comment: @chris little code example would be helpful

Comment: Somebody ? Anybody ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at doing this in XAML, but you can do it like this in the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void IncrementColumn(UIElement element)
    {
        Grid.SetColumn(element, Grid.GetColumn(element) + 1);
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        scrollPanel.ApplyTemplate();

        var horizontal = scrollPanel.Template.FindName("PART_HorizontalScrollBar", scrollPanel) as ScrollBar;
        var vertical = scrollPanel.Template.FindName("PART_VerticalScrollBar", scrollPanel) as ScrollBar;
        var presenter = scrollPanel.Template.FindName("PART_ScrollContentPresenter", scrollPanel) as ScrollContentPresenter;
        var corner = scrollPanel.Template.FindName("Corner", scrollPanel) as Rectangle;
        var grid = corner.Parent as Grid;

        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Insert(0, new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
        IncrementColumn(horizontal);
        IncrementColumn(vertical);
        IncrementColumn(corner);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(presenter, 2);

        var panel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
        panel.Children.Add(new ComboBox());
        panel.Children.Add(new Image());

        Grid.SetRow(panel, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(panel, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(panel);
    }
}
```

Here's the XAML to go with it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="525">
        <ScrollViewer
            Name="scrollPanel"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid              
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, great answer, I followed this approach and implemented it in XAML, works like a charm.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped you find the answer. I'd be keen to see your XAML solution. Could you add it to your question or something?